# Can't access nodejs port on browser virtual server

Tags: node.js, server

I'm running a nodejs application on my virtual host.
I just want to see the results of my index.js port 3000 on browser (I have tested all open ports) , but I will get connection time out with domain or server Ip.

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    var message = 'It works!\n',
        version = 'NodeJS ' + process.versions.node + '\n',
        response = [message, version].join('\n');
    res.end(response);
});
server.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log("Listening on port : " + 3000);
});
```

And I will start with `node index.js`

I can see the results with ssh command

```
curl https://localhost:3000
```

But when I can't see the results in browser
Any idea for this?

Answer (score 0):

You trying to access server via https protocol, however your server supports http

Comment: I use http for browser : ````http://x.x.x.x:3000```` (same with domain)
I still get connection timeout

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the default port by node js and the code you need to write is as follows

```
server.listen(3000 || process.ENV.PORT,function() 

{
   console.log("Listening on port : " +process.ENV.PORT);

});
```

Comment: Still the same issue